# Difference in light falling into a room depending on the positioning of the sun

Tags: photons, scattering, shadow

How does the lighting falling into a room differ in color temperature, shadow productions, directionality and other aspects, in relation to the positioning of the sun and the room?

For example, if the sun was high facing a window from the North, how would the natural lighting differ to the room on the opposite side with its window facing the South? Or a low sun facing a window from the north compared to the room on the other side with a window facing the south?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you assuming my hemisphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is dependent on a *lot* of variables, and human perception.  A simple answer will likely not suffice.

The first piece of the puzzle is the sky color.  Even when the sun isn't visible from the window, light comes through.  The color of the sky is complicated, but depends mostly on [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) and a bit of [Mie scatterning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering), the latter being more important at sunrise and sunset.

The color of the sun's light is basically the opposite of the sky.  It consists of all the colors that weren't scattered.  I couldn't find a complete model, but I did find this picture from an [article](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Color-temperature-variation-throughout-a-single-day_fig3_328726901) behind a paywall. (I can't read the article, so I can't speak to the assumptions they make)
[image: Color temperature of sun]

Now these are general statements about sunlight, regardless of which specific direction of window you are looking at.  If you apply physics to architecture, we do see specific differences for North facing windows and South facing windows.  In particular, there are seasonal differences.  If you are in the northern hemisphere, the sun is more southern in the sky during the winter, and more northern in the summer.  Architects can leverage this to manage heat loads.  South facing windows let in more heat from the sun during the winter, and less during the summer.

As for the other issues you raise, such as the effects of shadows from low or high windows, that is either trivial (lower windows cast longer shadows), or out of scope of Physics.SE (the artistic nuances of how you want to light a room).

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. The reason I ask about the shadows is more to do with the difference between light entering through a window where there is a direct path for the sunlight and it’s difference to a room not facing the sun, where I’m assuming most of the interior is being illuminated by the scattering of sunlight (assuming there are no other structures the lights could reflect off to get into the room). So would the shadows in the latter room be more “soft” (diffused) and cooler due to the plethora of shorter wavelengths?

Comment: The shadows will appear softer, but not primarily due to their color.  Sunlight comes from a relatively small source, which results in sharp edged shadows because the line between un-obscured and totally-obscured is short.  When there isn't a direct path, the light comes mostly from the sky, and the light comes from the entire surface of the window (a much larger area than the sun).  This makes the shadows "softer" because there's a larger blurry area where one is partially lit - by part of the window but not the other.  Its the same difference as a naked flash vs. a soft box in photography.

Comment: Yes okay that makes sense, thank you.